# What is this plant with clusters of purple berries at junctions of opposite serrated leaves?

Tags: identification, shrubs, nightshade

This plant has clusters of small purple berries at junctions where the leaves meet the stem. The leaves are a medium green color and serrated at the edges. It's from [Mission](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mission,_British_Columbia) in the [Lower Mainland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lower_Mainland) region of British Columbia, Canada.

Is it a nightshade?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it isn't nightshade, its Callicarpa americana, commonly known as Beauty berry. Many websites warn the berries are poisonous -they're not - but aren't at all tasty to eat anyway.

http://www.eattheweeds.com/beautyberry-jelly-on-a-roll/

Answer (score 2):

Looks like it's a Beauty Berry: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callicarpa